# Language specific URLs with UseDisplayName and LinkManager

Tags: multilingual, links, link-manager

We have a site where I need to add hreflang on each page, linking to each language version of the page.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://domain/pants" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://domain/bukser" hreflang="da">
```

The LinkManager is configured to use displaynames (useDisplayNames="true"):

```
<linkManager>
    <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">custom</patch:attribute>
    <providers>
      <add name="custom" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="true"/>
    </providers>
</linkManager>
```

I have tried getting the correct url by adding language to the UrlOptions and parse it to the LinkManager, but I keep getting the URL for the current langauge:

```
var urlOptions = UrlOptions.DefaultOptions;
urlOptions.Language = language;
var link = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
```

I have tried using a LanguageSwitcher, with the same result:

```
using (new LanguageSwitcher(lang))
{
    url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item, options);
}
```

It is a Sitecore 7.2

Anyone know how to get the language specific URL when using 'UseDisplayName' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're still trying to generate link to the item version which is in your language.

Try getting the other language version first:

```
var otherLanguageVersion = Sitecore.Context.Item.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID, language);
```

And then call:

```
LinkManager.GetItemUrl(otherLanguageVersion, options);
```